# hide just couple of html tags

Tags: php, html, tags

I have comment box. If i type in something like this

```
aa @Martins <aabb>
```

In database I save it like:

```
aa <span class="highlight" contenteditable="false">@Martins Vilskersts</span>&nbsp;&lt;aabb&gt;<span></span>
```

And for now i use this, to show it:

```
$str = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars_decode(html_entity_decode($my_string_from_database)), '<br><br/>');

//here is some replace for links functionality
$replace = '<a href="javascript:;" class="..." id="..." ></a>';
$str = str_replace($link->tag, $replace, $str);

echo $str;
```

And i get result like this:

```
aa @Martins
```

But i want to see it like this:

```
aa @Martins <aabb> -[with @ functionality, but with some random <aaa><bbb> tags as plain text. Any idea?]
```

Comment: are you trying to create tags ??

Comment: I just want, if user write <aabbcc>, then see it like text, but for now it just disapear!

Comment: You should be happy that it dissapears... Or would you like, that i post a `<script>`tag?

Comment: le me get this straight !
you want to write this <aabbcc>
enter into the database as it is 
and you want to show it you just want the text not those tags brackets ?? right?

Comment: Nope. I need to see <aabbcc> as it is. But strip_tags delete it.

Comment: @pc-shooter yes, if user write <script> i want too see it as text - <script>

Comment: if user is allowed to type <script> tags, he can input malicious javascript into your site, not a clever idea

Answer (score 0):

**USE THIS:**

just replace `<` by `&lt`; and `>` by `&gt`;

**Keep this in mid as well :**

'&' (ampersand) becomes &

'"' (double quote) becomes " when ENT_NOQUOTES is not set.

"'" (single quote) becomes ' only when ENT_QUOTES is set.

'<' (less than) becomes <

'>' (greater than) becomes >

Answer (score 0):

If you just literally output the string as stored in the database, without using htmlspecialchars_decode, strip_tags, html_entity_encode, etc, then it'll come out properly.

You have already saved the parts you want to see as encoded characters, and the parts that should work as raw html in your database.

Comment: Nope. It print out <span> as text, but i need hide it.